# Handling SNI with pyOpenSSL - Python

Tags: python, ssl, https, sni

I'm working with `pyOpenSSL` lately, however I came across some urls that use `SNI` to present multiple certificates for the same IP address. Here's my code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from socket import socket
from sys import argv, stdout
import re
from urlparse import urlparse

def callback(conn, cert, errno, depth, result):
    if depth == 0 and (errno == 9 or errno == 10):
        return False # or raise Exception("Certificate not yet valid or expired")
    return True

def main():
    if len(argv) < 2:
            print 'Usage: %s <hostname>' % (argv[0],)
            return 1

    o = urlparse(argv[1])
    host_name = o.netloc
    context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_METHOD) # Use TLS Method
    context.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2) # Don't accept SSLv2
    context.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER | SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
                       callback)
    # context.load_verify_locations(ca_file, ca_path)

    sock = socket()
    ssl_sock = SSL.Connection(context, sock)
    ssl_sock.connect((host_name, 443))
    ssl_sock.do_handshake()

    cert = ssl_sock.get_peer_certificate()
    common_name = cert.get_subject().commonName.decode()
    print "Common Name: ", common_name
    print "Cert number: ", cert.get_serial_number()
    regex = common_name.replace('.', r'\.').replace('*',r'.*') + '$'
    if re.match(regex, host_name):
        print "matches"
    else:
        print "invalid"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example, let's say I have the following url:

```
https://example.com
```

When I get the following output:

```
python sni.py https://example.com/
Common Name:  *.example.com
Cert number:  63694395280496902491340707875731768741
invalid
```

which is the same certificate for `https://another.example.com`:

```
python sni.py https://another.example.com/
Common Name:  *.example.com
Cert number:  63694395280496902491340707875731768741
matches
```

However, let's say, the certificate for `https://another.example.com` is expired, the connection will be accepted anyways, since it's using the `*.example.com` certificate, which is valid. However I want to be able to use `https://another.example.com/` and if it's not valid, reject the connection outright. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `set_tlsext_host_name`. From [the documentation](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ssl.html#OpenSSL.SSL.Connection.set_tlsext_host_name):

```
Connection.set_tlsext_host_name(name)
  Specify the byte string to send as the server name in the client hello message.
  New in version 0.13.
```

Apart from that your hostname validation is wrong since it only compares against the CN and not the subject alternative names. Also it allows wildcards on any place which is against the rule that wildcards should only be allowed in the leftmost label: `*.example.com` is fine while `www.*.com` or even `*.*.*` is not allowed but accepted by your code.

Comment: Could you please formulate more on the hostname verification?

Comment: @philippe: how proper hostname validation is done would actually be outside of your original question. But it essentially boils down to checking against subject alternative names (SAN) first and use only CN if no hostnames are given in SAN. And wildcards can only be in the leftmost label. For more details see [RFC6125](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125) or look at  the implementation of the `match_hostname` function in ssl.py.